# C# and ASP.NET MCQs

Tags: c#, .net

From where I can get multiple choice questions about C# and asp.net?

Comment: This belongs on StackOverflow

Comment: @Tundey - that's debatable. The poster is looking for quiz questions, not actual programming advice.

Answer (score 0):

Take a few [Brainbench](http://www.brainbench.com/) C# / ASP.NET tests and copy their questions? They're all MC..